# The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008

I am trying to upload a excel file  in a asp.net website and process the fields into  dataset
for further operation . but i am getting a message as above .

i have tried with  other options of exception - will list those

ex.message - The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

ex.Source  - App_Web_-we0qvgj

ex.StackTrace  -

> at
>   frmStudentExcelRegistration.ExcelToDataset(String
>   FileName) in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CATALYST_SECONDARY\Pages\frmStudentExcelRegistration.aspx.cs:line
>   449  at
>   frmStudentExcelRegistration.btnExcelUpload_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)  in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\CATALYST_SECONDARY\Pages\frmStudentExcelRegistration.aspx.cs:line
>   488
>
> ex.TargetSite - System.Data.DataSet
>   ExcelToDataset(System.String)

operating system is windows server 2008 .

I went through  some of the forums and they told to change the application pool default setting in IIS Manager to allow 32 bit applications . after doing so I am getting the error message as  -

"Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. "

can anyone help ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JET engine is installed by default - however, it is 32-bit only. The problem arises when you're running an application in 64-bit mode. I've had the same problem for Desktop applications.

As you're creating an ASP.NET application, changing the app pool is the correct way. As sehe said, the ViewState message is unrelated to this.

Answer (score 1):

Your Excel is being opened as a dataset. This requires the MS Jet Engine (which is part of MDAC).

Download it here: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q239114

The ViewState message is unrelated and was caused by restarting the server (and posting back from a browser session that had been opened before that restart).

Answer (score 0):

If you need 64bit and JET, you can download it here
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en